# Convert Date from json to datetime

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, datetime

I have a function that sends a step to my c# controller.

```
$scope.saveProgress = function () {

    var step6 = {
        Id: $scope.stepId,
        ProblemId: $scope.problemId,
        WhenOptions: $scope.whenOptions,
        CounterMeasures: $scope.counterMeasures,
        CounterMeasureWhens: $scope.counterMeasureWhens,
        CompletedDate: $scope.CompletedDate
        // step 6 specific data
    };

    $http.post(ROOT + '/step/SaveA3Step6/', step6)
        .success(function (result) {
            // log to console?
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log to console?
        });
};
```

Everything sends fine but the date always ends up as null in my c# controller.

```
public JsonResult SaveA3Step6(A3Step6 a3Step6)
    {
        try
        {
            a3Step6.Save();
            return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("Error" + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

When debugging I find that `$scope.CompletedDate` is in the format `"/Date(1426636800000)/"`.
And because my A3Step6 object in c# is expecting a datetime its showing null.

Is there a way of converting my `$scope.CompletedDate` to a datetime in my `$scope.saveProgress` function before I post it back to my c# controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the Date Filter of Angularjs. You have to inject the $filter in the controller's constructor.

```
var cpltDate = $filter('date')($scope.CompletedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
var step6 = {
    Id: $scope.stepId,
    ProblemId: $scope.problemId,
    WhenOptions: $scope.whenOptions,
    CounterMeasures: $scope.counterMeasures,
    CounterMeasureWhens: $scope.counterMeasureWhens,
    CompletedDate: cpltDate
};
```

The full document for the date filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to specify the format needed for parsing the date.

For example, if having a datetime of the following format in JS :

```
var d = Date(2015,3,18,11,22,25,0)
'Wed Mar 18 2015 11:28:35 GMT+0200'
```

You can parse it in C# with the following command :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(a3Step6,
                                  "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss GMTzzzzz",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Date().toJSON()
```

should work too. Instead of new Date() use any javascript Date object you want. The default MVC modelbinder handles this well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, it seems is that`$scope.CompletedDate` is the string command of date (`"Date(1426636800000)"`). It must be evaluated to obtain the date.

Using `eval($scope.CompletedDate)` or `eval($scope.CompletedDate).toUTCString()` might solve the issue.

```
var step6 = {
    Id: $scope.stepId,
    ProblemId: $scope.problemId,
    WhenOptions: $scope.whenOptions,
    CounterMeasures: $scope.counterMeasures,
    CounterMeasureWhens: $scope.counterMeasureWhens,
    CompletedDate: eval($scope.CompletedDate)
    // step 6 specific data
};
```